# Automaticly redirect to a static page on high traffic with Nginx

Tags: performance, nginx

Is there a way with Nginx to redirect a user to a static page when the number of simultaneous connections is too high ?

Comment: May what you need is a http balancer. You can do it with nginx too, there is the link to the [official web page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `limit_req_zone` you can redefine 503 to a custom page.

Comment: is limit_req_zone working for limiting single IPs of for all traffic ?